# Merge two adjacent polygons in a 3D space

Tags: python, polygon, 3d

Given two three-dimensional polygons that are both in the same winding order (counter-clockwise order or in clockwise order):

```
poly1 = np.array([[120787.075999871, 491779.675000143, -2.0699999332428], [120784.319999829, 491781.831000042, 5.96999979019165], [120784.319999829, 491781.831000042, -2.0699999332428], [120787.075999871, 491779.675000143, -2.0699999332428]])
poly2 = np.array([[120787.075999871, 491779.675000143, -2.03999996185303], [120787.075999871, 491779.675000143, 5.90999984741211], [120784.319999829, 491781.831000042, 5.96999979019165], [120787.075999871, 491779.675000143, -2.03999996185303]])
```

How can I combine / merge these adjacent polygons into a single polygon (in Python) while keeping the order.

Here is a code to plot the two adjacent polygons:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(poly1[:,0],poly1[:,1],poly1[:,2])
ax.plot(poly2[:,0],poly2[:,1],poly2[:,2])
ax.view_init(45, 45) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me, but I will suggest asking this question on a normal SE

Comment: There does not appear to be a GIS component to your question which may be better researched/asked at [so].